# How can I use Tesseract Android Tools in Android Studio?

Tags: image-processing, android-studio, ocr, tesseract

I am trying to make an app for android which may fetch out text from image. But I'm not able to find any way possible to use Tesseract Android Tools in Android Studio. Can someone help me out?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you tried and where your attempt ran into problems.

Answer (score 0):

There's a useful tutorial written by a guy called Gautam Gupta that I would recommend you to read to set things up for using the Tesseract OCR. [Here](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/)

Also, a user has posted a comment below the page giving users step-by-step instructions on how to set everything up using Android Studio [Here](http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/#comment-184181)

Make sure you follow every step carefully.